# Writing a C function sprod (n,x,y) that returns the scalar product of 2 1-D arrays of type float

Tags: c, math

Write a C function, sprod (n,x,y), that returns the scalar product of 2 1-D arrays of type float. The function takes as input variables the size n (type int variable) of the arrays and pointers x and y to the first member of each array, and returns a float result. The main() code block needs to call sprod to compute the matrix product a*b where the type float matrix a and type float vector b given by b=[1 1 1] and a=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9] (where a is a 3x3 matrix).

We can initialize b in a f(;;) loop and a in a double for(;;) loop (or use a lot of assignment statements). The matrix product should be computed by using calls to the function sprod to form the scalar products of each of the rows of a with the vector b; pointers to these rows are given by a[1], a[2], and a[3]. Lastly, a for(;;) loop to sum the resulting scalar products and the printf() function to print the result to the screen should also be used.

The result should be the sum of all of the elements of the matrix a. Copies of the matrix a and vector b should also be printed. We are to use the Numerical Recipes C functions matrix() and vector() with free_matrix() and free_vector() to create a and b as dynamically defined arrays.

I am a beginner when it comes to programming and I have found that I really suck at it. This is what I have so far and it blows up like crazy when it is compiled (I know some things have been left out). I tried using gdb to debug it, but I couldn't get that to work either. Any help would be appreciated.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include "nrutil.h"
# include "nrutil.c"

void transp(float **a,int n);
float sprod(int n, float *x, float *y);
int main()
{
  int i,j;
  float var=0.0, sum=0.0, pro=0.0;
  float*b, **a;
  int n=3;
  float index;
  b=vector(0,n-1);
  a=matrix(0,n-1,0,n-1);

  printf("\nVector b\n");
  for(j=0;j<n;j++)
  {
    b[j]=1;
    printf("%.2f\n",b[j]);
  }
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    for(j=0;j<n;j++);
    {
      var=var+1;
      a[i][j]=var;
    }
  }
  printf("\n Matrix a\n");
  for(i=0;i<n;i++);
  {
    for(j=0;j<n;j++);
    {
      printf("%.2lf",a[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  printf("\nProduct of Matrix a and Vector b\n");

  for(i=0;i<n;i++);
  {
    pro=sprod(n,a[i],b);
    printf("%.2f\n",pro);
    sum+=pro;
  }
  printf("\n Sum of Product array\n");
  printf("%.2f\n\n", sum);
  free_ivector(index,0,n-1);
  free_matrix(a,0,n-1,0,n-1);

  return 0;
}

float sprod(int n, float *x, float *y)
{
  float scalar=0.0;
  int j=0;
  int sum=0;

  for(j=0;j<n;j++);
  {
    scalar+=x[j]*y[j];
  }
  return scalar;
 }
```

I have refined my code since originally posting this. Now it almost works I am just having trouble with line 50 the free_ivector bit of code. The terminal tells me: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘free_ivector’. I'm not really sure what that means. The code takes the overall formatting of what David Duncan suggested in the first answer below.

Comment: 1. Where are your prototypes? 2. You have a closing curly brace in the codeline 11 and you didn't fill `a[3,3]` with anything? 3. for lops without any arguments? try to help us to understand your code improving it a bit more! :)

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto: the homework tag is not to be used.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks, I won't use it anymore, but it looks like a homework.

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto: Agreed, but [The homework tag is now officially deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).

Comment: What do you mean prototypes? The curly brackets was a mistake and I was not sure what to put for a[3,3] so I left it blank. Are you supposed to define the matrix here? The part of the code that starts "float i;" (the middle section) is where the arrays are supposed to be created. After that the "float *index,i;" creates the the vector, b. The section above those two is the main program. What do you mean the loops with no arguments? I thought you could create an infinite for loop just by using f(;;)? I don't understand a lot of this so this may be about as improved as I can make it.

Comment: Ha! @paddy. Definitely does not.

Comment: @Sprock I don't want to sound pedantic but you need to practice a bit more. Prototypes are the functions declarations and they are always declared before the main.

Comment: I think this is a homework, he needs to fill the fields or something like that.

Comment: I forgot about those too. I havent heard them referred to as prototypes before. You dont sound pedantic.

Comment: It was never explained to me that in order to use gdb the code had to compile. That explains why I could not get it to work. Also, to clarify this is a homework assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a hard problem for someone uncomfortable with programming or even just C, since it involves pointers and passing array references.  I think you know enough to look up examples of each specific item you need, though, and so your first goal--as you probably know--is to break things down into subproblems and tackle them individually (and iteratively, if need be).  Since your current code could use a little help with the layout, I've adapted the problem statement into something you can tackle piece-by-piece.  Replace each "TODO" comment with code that does that and I believe you'll be done.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "nrutil.h"

float sprod(int n, float *x, float *y)
{
    float result = 0.0;
    // TODO: Calculate result (hint: for loop repeating n times,
    // and each iteration you'll update result)

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    // TODO: Create and initialize matrix A
    // TODO: Create and initialize matrix B
    // TODO: Print A and B
    // TODO: For each row of A, call sprod() with that row of A
    // and B as inputs, and save each sprod() result
    // TODO: Sum the results
    // TODO: Print the sum

    return 0; // (0 indicates success; if you were to have
              //  failure cases, you could return other values)
}
```

Using the above approach also will facilitate compiling as you go (and consequently, being able to use the debugger).  An absolute bare minimum for using GDB is the following:

- Compile with the GCC -g switch--i.e., `gcc -g myprog.c`
- `gdb <program name>` (program name will typically be a.exe and or a.out by default)
- `break <line number>` to set a breakpoint
- `run` to start the program
- `n` for the next statement
- `quit` to quit

Also, there are also a couple of things in the original problem statement that I see as a bit confusing if it were provided by the teacher (if it's just your paraphrasing things, I'm nitpicking):

- for(;;) results in an infinite loop, unless within it you use a goto statement (very atypical) or a break statement (somewhat atypical), neither of which would be appropriate here.  So it would have made a bit more sense to just say "for loop".
- Just to be clear, C has zero-based indexing, meaning unless matrix() explicitly defines it as such, your rows would be a[0], a[1], and a[2] (not a[1], a[2], and a[3]).

Comment: Thanks for this. That makes it a lot easier to understand what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

To give an idea:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define ROW 3
#define MAT 9

float printinv( int n, float * a, float * b );

int main ( void ){
    int i, k;
    float a[ ROW ] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    float b[ MAT ] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    float *c;
    c = &b[0];


    printf( "A = " );
    for( i = 0; i < ROW; i++ ){
        if( i == 0 )
            printf( "[" );
        if ( i != ROW - 1 )
            printf( "  %5.2f", a[ i ] );
        else {
            printf( "  %5.2f", a[ i ] );
            printf( "  ]" );
        }
    }

    printf( "    B = " );
    for( i = k = 0; k < MAT; k++ ){
        if( i == 0 && k == 0) 
            printf("[");
        else if( i == 0 && k > 0 )
            printf( "                                     [");
        if( i != ROW - 1 ){
            printf( "  %5.2f", b[ k ] );
            i++;
        }
        else{
            printf( "  %5.2f", b[ k ] );
            printf( "  ]\n" );
            i = 0;
        }
    }

    printf( "C = " );
    for( i = 0; i < ROW; i++ ){
        if( i == 0 ) 
            printf("[");
        if( i != ROW - 1 )
            printf( "  %5.2f", printinv( MAT, ( c + i ), a ) );
        else{
            printf( "  %5.2f", printinv( MAT, ( c + i ), a ) );
            printf( "  ]\n" );
        }
    }
    getchar();

}

float printinv( int n, float * b, float * a )
{
    int i, k;
    float result;
    float x, y;

    for( result = i = 0; i < ROW; i++ ){
        k = i * ROW;
        result += b[ k ] * a[ i ];
        x = b[ k ]; 
        y = a[ i ];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: -What does this code do? Is this an example of how to take the scalar product? Also what does the printinv do?